# Multi domain SSL?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

A co-worker told me that when you visit a website over SSL the certificate no longer guarantees that you're actually dealing with the intended recipient.  This is due to something called "multi-domain SSL certificates".  A quick google search seems to show these exist - but I was always under the impression SSL provided encryption *and* authentication.  Is this no longer the case?  Surely this is a step in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are wildcard certificates, which allow all hosts in one domain to be covered by the same cert. They're more expensive to get issued (since the CAs wouldn't make as much money as if you'd ordered multiple separate single-domain certs), but when you need to cover multiple hostnames in your domain with ssl, it can be quite a savings.

A properly issued cert will cover at LEAST one host name, like www.example.com. And with wildcarding, can cover *.example.com.

SSL by itself guarantees nothing in the way of identification - simply that the link is encrypted. Any certificate will do that for you - even self-signed ones. What you get with the "commercial" certs is a (theoretically) trustworthy third party saying "we've verified that the person who this www.example.com certificate was issused to really is www.example.com"

Comment: Well, in addition to wildcard certificates, there are also multi-domain certificates. They are intended to cover multiple different domains. For example yoursite.com, yoursite.net, yoursite-2.org, all with a single certificate. However, they are still just as secure as any other regular certificates.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to given answer, i would like to add few points about SAN (multidomain SSL). First of all, wildcard is not a multi-domain ssl, it only protects unlimited sub-domains as already explained by Marc.

To protect multiple domains like:

```
domain.net
domain.com
mail.domain.com
newdomain.com
```

you will require SAN certificates that start from just $60.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure multi domain with SSL on both UBUNTU and REDHAT by following the document [Multi domian with ssl](https://kalaivairamuthu.wordpress.com/2019/06/13/ssl-configuation-for-multiple-domain/)